# Yum php-yaml install issues

Tags: yum, vagrant, repository, php

We had an issue with an **ansible playbook** using **vagrant** - where formerly php-yaml was installing fine.

Then, we were getting issues with our PHP repo:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install php-yaml
...
Error: Package: php-pecl-yaml-1.1.1-5.el6.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: php(api) = 20090626
       Installed: php-common-5.5.16-1.el6.remi.2.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
           php(api) = 20121113-64
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php(api) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
           php(api) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
           php(api) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.2.x86_64 (updates)
           php(api) = 20090626
       Available: php-common-5.4.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
       Available: php-common-5.4.33-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
       Available: php-common-5.5.17-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           php(api) = 20121113-64
       Available: php-common-5.5.17-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           php(api) = 20121113-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the most pretty - but this was our solution:

```
yum install libyaml
yum --disablerepo=epel install php-pecl-yaml
```

We needed epel to get libyaml but we did not want epel with php-pecl-yaml

This allowed us to continue to use **php-extension** instead of **php55-php-extension**